# Yii v1 Left Join giving CDbException

Tags: mysql, join, yii, left-join

I am trying to do an LEFT Join in Yii v.1 Mysql .
There are alreday 4 tables joined and I want to join this table also.

```
$cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();

$selectString .= "table2.dir_pic, table2.pic1, table2.pic2 , table2.pic3 "; 


 $cmd->select($selectString);
  $cmd->from('table1');

$cmd->leftjoin('table2', 'table1.id=table2.user_entry_id');
 $entries = $cmd->queryAll();
        $this->render('index', compact('entries', 'model'));
```

It is giving an CDbException

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`dir_pic`, `table2`.`pic1`, `table2`.`pic2`, ' at line 1.
```

I tried this query in mysql(phpmyadmin)

```
    SELECT table1.id,table2.dir_pic,table2.pic1,table2.pic2, table2.pic3 FROM 
table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.user_entry_id
```

and It shows proper output.BUt not when I try in Yii .

Comment: You are missing part of the exception. It should say _CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version _**for the right syntax to use near...**

Comment: @G45 yes, There is an big exception as 7 tables are used ,But I'll add first line of the exception.I hope It will give you clear Idea

Comment: The code you've given works without a problem. It should be something with the code you've not posted here. Double check $selectString building steps and examine the error message in detail. Then you may find the problem. Unable to answer without proper details.

Comment: @Captain Thanks for the Help and yes the code given had no issue, I found the solution.
Actually I missed an comma (,) after the end of previous $selectString query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually I missed an comma (,) after the end of previous $selectString query.